# Google Ads in Electron?

Tags: javascript, adsense, electron

I'm writing an Electron app that I'd like to place Google ads in, but I'm not sure how to correctly do it.

I've created my ad snippet and put it in my app. The default snippet uses `//googleads.g.doubleclick.net ...` as the URL for the adsbygoogle.js file, so I had to change that to `https://googleads.g.doubleclick.net ...` because the Electron app uses `file:///` to load the index page.

But after doing that, the adsbygoogle.js file throws up a 400 error which is strange.

And on top of that, I'm not sure how to handle a user clicking on ads. To get the link to my website working, I had to create a link that pointed to `javascript:shell.openExternal('https://example.com')`, but I'm not sure how to do that with external ads.

So how can I put ads in my Electron app?

Comment: Have you found some other ads that are allowed in electron ?

Comment: @JordanKanchelov no, I ended up giving up on the Electron app (because ultimately it didn't fit the scope of my project). Sorry!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

**Google AdSense is not allowed in any desktop applications.**

From [AdSense policy](http://www.google.com/adsense/policies#pla):

> Google ads, search boxes or search results may not be:
>
> - **Integrated into a software application of any kind, including toolbars.**
> - Displayed in pop-ups or pop-unders.
> - Placed in emails, email programs, or chat programs.
> - Obscured by elements on a page.
> - Placed on any non-content-based page. (Does not apply to AdSense for search or mobile AdSense for search.)
> - Placed on pages published specifically for the purpose of showing ads.
> - Placed on pages whose content or URL could confuse users into thinking it is associated with Google due to the misuse of logos,
>     trademarks or other brand features.
> - Placed on, within or alongside other Google products or services in a manner that violates the policies of that product or service.

Comment: I suspected that, but wasn't sure, since Electron apps are technically web pages displayed through Chromium.

I'll have a look over the rest of the Adsense site to learn more. Thanks!

Comment: Is it possible to show ads by using a webkit view ..? i am thinking of a web page where i will place ads and then fetch and render inside electron!!! - Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I don't sure about Electron but Node Webkit (very similar technology) allows creation app from any given url.

So, you can actually host your app in the web (with running AdSense ads on it) and create installation package for Node Webkit app.

When installed it will be just regular browser showing by default your web app (with AdSense).

There is no way (IMHO) to Google to distinct Chromium browser downloaded from your site or Download.com to same Chromium browser downloaded from google.com.

Answer (score -1):

I think you can do some Iframe html tag and display your website with the ads in it !
but idk if this is count as a view.

Comment: Can you expand your answer a bit? It's a bit vague at the moment.